# Create a list of different groups/packs

Tags: netlogo, turtle-graphics

Each agent of my model has a turtle-own variable which indicates that they are part of a particular family group.

I am trying to create a global variable which is a list of the different 'family groups' present.

I figured I just need a list of all agents family identifier then remove the duplicates? But for the life of me I can't figure this out.

Something like

```
let o-family-groups list family-name of turtles
set family-groups remove-duplicates o-family-groups
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to the acutal solution.
You can drop the `list` primitive, because `[turtles-own-var] of turtles` will report you a list anyways. However, you have to put the turtle-own variable in brackets [].

```
let o-family-groups [family-name] of turtles
set family-groups remove-duplicates (o-family-groups)
```

You could also add the `remove-duplicates` into the same line to make the code even shorter:

```
set family-groups remove-duplicates ([family-name] of turtles)
```

Comment: @H.Tan: If this solved your problem, you may want to accept Tyr’s answer.